# Playing sound from a video using FFmpeg and SDL_QueueAudio results in high pitched audio

Tags: ffmpeg, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to play audio from an mp4 file using SDL2 and FFmpeg, and using `SDL_QueueAudio` seems much easier than setting up a callback.

All solutions I've found, whether here or in the [dranger tutorials](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.html), are deprecated or use callbacks.  I tried browsing all questions with both the ffmpeg and sdl tags (there aren't many), to no avail.  I tried converting the dranger tutorial to use non-deprecated calls but ran into the same problem.  I'm using C, FFmpeg 4.1 and SDL 2.0.9.

This is the setup for AVCodecContext and AVCodec:

```c
    int audioStream = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (audioStream < 0 && formatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioStream = i;
        }
    }

    AVCodecParameters *audioParams = formatContext->streams[audioStream]->codecpar;

    AVCodec *audioCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(audioParams->codec_id);

    AVCodecContext *audioCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(NULL);
    avcodec_open2(audioCodecCtx, audioCodec, NULL);

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO)

    SDL_AudioSpec desired, obtained;
    SDL_zero(desired);
    SDL_zero(obtained);
    desired.freq = audioCodecCtx->sample_rate;
    desired.format = AUDIO_F32SYS;
    desired.channels = audioCodecCtx->channels;
    desired.silence = 0;
    desired.samples = AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;

    SDL_AudioDeviceID audioDevice = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &desired, &obtained, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);
```

This is the main packet decoding loop:

```c
    while (av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == audioStream) {
            if (!avcodec_send_packet(audioCodecCtx, &packet)) {
                avcodec_receive_frame(audioCodecCtx, audioFrame);
                SDL_QueueAudio(audioDevice, audioFrame->data[0], audioFrame->linesize[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The audio plays at the correct speed but at a much higher pitch than what it actually is.  I would like it to sound the same as in any media player.
Edit:  I just realized the test video has stereo audio but I'm only queueing `audioFrame.data[0]`, which I assume means I'm only playing one channel.  I tried queueing `audioFrame.data[1]` which has data as well but it did not solve the problem.  Am I correct and if so, how do I play both channels?

Comment: Have you checked values in `obtained` structure (mostly frequency)?

Comment: For my test video, ```obtained.freq``` is 44100, which is the same as what VLC reports.

Answer (score 2):

May be too late to answer this question, but I faced the same problem and now I found the solution that works for me, so I'm posting this.
The problem here is, probably, that the audio format decoded by FFmpeg is AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP (float planer) format where channels are stored separately like `frame->data[0]` and `frame->data[1]`.
We need to convert it to a format which packs those channels into one array using swr_convert()
And here's my solution.

1. SwrContext set up

```cpp
SwrContext *resampler = swr_alloc_set_opts(NULL, 
                                           audioCodecCtx->channel_layout,
                                           AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16,
                                           44100,
                                           audioCodecCtx->channel_layout,
                                           audioCodecCtx->sample_fmt,
                                           audioCodecCtx->sample_rate,
                                           0, 
                                           NULL);
swr_init(resampler);
```

2. SDL Audio set up

```cpp
SDL_AudioDeviceID dev;
SDL_AudioSpec want, have;
SDL_zero(want);
SDL_zero(have);
want.freq = 44100;
want.channels = audioCodecCtx->channels;
want.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;
dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &want, &have, 0);
SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
```

finally the decoding loop

```cpp
int ret = 0;
AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVFrame *audioframe = av_frame_alloc();
while (true){
    ret = av_read_frame(formatContext, packet);
    if (ret < 0) break;
    AVStream *stream = formatContext->streams[packet->stream_index];
    if (stream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){
        ret = avcodec_send_packet(audioCodecCtx, packet);
        while (ret >= 0){
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(audioCodecCtx, frame);
            if (ret >= 0){
                int dst_samples = frame->channels * av_rescale_rnd(
                                   swr_get_delay(resampler, frame->sample_rate)
                                   + frame->nb_samples,
                                   44100,
                                   frame->sample_rate,               
                                   AV_ROUND_UP);
                uint8_t *audiobuf = NULL;
                ret = av_samples_alloc(&audiobuf, 
                                       NULL, 
                                       1, 
                                       dst_samples,
                                       AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 
                                       1);
                dst_samples = frame->channels * swr_convert(
                                                 resampler, 
                                                 &audiobuf, 
                                                 dst_samples,
                                                 (const uint8_t**) frame->data, 
                                                 frame->nb_samples);
                ret = av_samples_fill_arrays(audioframe->data, 
                                             audioframe->linesize, 
                                             audiobuf,
                                             1, 
                                             dst_samples, 
                                             AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, 
                                             1);
                SDL_QueueAudio(dev, 
                               audioframe->data[0], 
                               audioframe->linesize[0]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adjusting the frequency. Try changing the frequency to something like `audioCodecCtx->sample_rate * 0.5`.